# Time flies like an arrow demo in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive

Looking at the Reactive Extensions for javascript demo on [Jeff Van Gogh's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffva/archive/2010/03/17/reactive-extensions-for-javascript-the-time-flies-like-an-arrow-sample.aspx), I thought I'd give it a try in C#/Winforms, but it doesn't seem to work so well.

I just threw this into the constructor of a form (with the Rx framework installed and referenced):

```
Observable.Context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
var mousemove = Observable.FromEvent<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove");
var message = "Time flies like an arrow".ToCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
{
    var l = new Label() 
            { 
                Text = message[i].ToString(), 
                AutoSize = true, 
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter 
            };
    int closure = i;
    mousemove
        .Delay(closure * 150)
        .Subscribe(e => 
            {
                l.Left = e.EventArgs.X + closure * 15 + 10;
                l.Top = e.EventArgs.Y;
                //Debug.WriteLine(l.Text);
            });
    Controls.Add(l);
}
```

When I move the mouse, the letters seem to get moved in a random order, and if I uncomment the Debug line, I see multiple events for the same letter...

Any ideas? I've tried Throttle, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Am I just asking too much of WinForms to move all those labels around?

(Cross posted on [Rx Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/2532ef4d-9b44-4017-927b-30812ca74ea0))

Answer (score 2):

*Answer cross posted back from [Rx Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/2532ef4d-9b44-4017-927b-30812ca74ea0) (if the author is here and wants to claim it, that's fine by me):*

Problem #1: You are using old bits. Observable.Context was gone about 4 versions ago.
Problem #2: Javascript has no concept of threads, and Rx likes to put stuff on other threads for you.

So, using the latest bits, the solution looks something like this:

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Reactive("Time flies like an arrow");
}

private void Reactive(string msg)
{
    var mousemove = Observable.FromEvent<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove");
    var message = msg.ToCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
    {
        var l = new Label()
        { 
            Text = message[i].ToString(), 
            AutoSize = true, 
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter 
        };
        int closure = i;
        mousemove
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.07 * i), Scheduler.Dispatcher)
            .Subscribe(e =>
            {
                l.Left = e.EventArgs.X + closure * 12 - 5;
                l.Top = e.EventArgs.Y + 15;
            });
        Controls.Add(l);
    }
}
```

Notice the ObserveOnDispatcher and SubscribeOnDispatcher. This brings us close to the Javascript version, but again threading is the real issue here.

**UPDATE**, added correction from Jeff Van Gogh in above code

---

Just for fun, here is a vague rendering of the same thing without Rx:

```
private void Unreactive(string msg)
{
    var message = msg.ToCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
    {
        var l = new Label()
        { 
            Text = message[i].ToString(), 
            AutoSize = true, 
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter 
        };
        Controls.Add(l);
        int closure = i;
        this.MouseMove += (s, e) => LabelDelayMove(closure, e, l);
    }
}

private void LabelDelayMove(int i, MouseEventArgs e, Label l)
{
    Point p = new Point(e.X + i * 12 - 5, e.Y - 15);
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((_) => LabelMove(l, p), null, i * 70, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}

private void LabelMove(Label l, Point location)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => l.Location = location));
}
```

Comment: Link to the original post?  Ah, I see it in your question, but not this answer.

Comment: @Richard, yup, I've added a link to the question, but can't for the life of me see where there might be a link to the answer. They really should drop their forums and come over here to join the party!